# sufficient condition for a real matrix to have all real eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We all know that eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix are real, but I am looking for sufficient conditions for a general real matrix (not necessarily symmetric) to have only real eigenvalues. So far, I know that totally positive matrices have this property I want. Are there any other sufficient conditions besides total positivity?

Comment: This may be useful:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669499/what-properties-should-a-matrix-have-if-all-its-eigenvalues-are-real

From it, $A$ has real eigenvalues $\iff A\sim U$, where $U$ is an upper triangular matrix with real diagonal entries, and $\sim$ is the standard $A\sim B\iff A=PBP^{-1}$ for $P$ invertible.

Comment: [This MO question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/20946) is also related, although it doesn't really address your question.