# Real matrices having all eigenvalues real

Tags: linear-algebra

What properties do a real matrices need to satisfy so that all its eigenvalues are real?

I know very well that real symmetric matrices have this property. But they do not form an exhaustive set. I have also checked this question ([What properties should a matrix have if all its eigenvalues are real?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669499/what-properties-should-a-matrix-have-if-all-its-eigenvalues-are-real)) but the property is not practically checkable.

I need a characterization for real matrices having real eigenvalues.

Comment: There are things such as "is similar to an upper (or lower) triangular matrix", but I doubt any of them are easier to _test_ than "all eigenvalues are real".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that this is an old post but hopefully somebody is still interested. There is an old result of Emilie Haynsworth and Michael Drazin that a necessary and sufficient condition for a real matrix $A$ to have all real eigenvalues with $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors is that there exists a positive semidefinite matrix $S$ such that $AS$ is a symmetric matrix.

In the case where $S$ is positive definite then $A$ is self-adjoint under a modified inner product: $\langle v,w\rangle=v^T S w$

The Drazin-Haynsworth paper is below. Haynsworth wrote a number of nice papers on questions like this in the 60's.

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01195188

I don't know if you want the matrices to have no eigenvector deficiency. If one drops the requirement that the matrix have $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors then I don't know but I doubt that there is a very nice condition. I hope that you find this helpful.