# Eigenvalues of $A+B$ in this special case

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ are real, square matrices with the same dimension. We know that $\text{rank } A = 1$ and we know the eigenvalues of $A$. Furthermore, we know that $B$ has only zeros in the diagonal, but we don't know anything else about $B$.

Can we say something about the eigenvalues of $A+B$ ?

Or in general, can we say anything about the eigenvalues of sum of two arbitrary non-symmetric  matrices?

Answer (score 2):

First let us note that since $\text{rank}(A)=1$, $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ of multiplicity $n-1$. Then the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $0,0,0,..,0, \text{tr}(A)$.

Therefore, since $\text{rank}(A)=1$, saying that we know the eigenvalues of $A$ is equivalent to saying that we know $\text{tr}(A)$.

Moreover, as $\text{tr}(A+B)=\text{tr}(A)+\text{tr}(B)=\text{tr}(A)$, the sum of eigenvalues of $A+B$ must be $\text{tr}(A)$.

Let $a_1,\cdots,a_n\in\mathbb{R}:a_1+\cdots+a_n =\text{tr}(A)$. Then, $a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are the eigenvalues of $A+B$, where

$$A= \begin{bmatrix} a_1 & a_1 & \cdots & a_1  \\
a_2 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_n & a_n & \cdots & a_n \end{bmatrix}  \\
B= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -a_1 & \cdots & -a_1  \\
-a_2 &0 & \cdots & -a_2 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
-a_n & -a_n & \cdots &0\end{bmatrix} $$

Moreover, because of the above comments, $A$ has the given eigenvalues.

We finish by covering the case  $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$. They are eigenvalues of $A+B$, where
$$A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \\
B= 0 $$

Comment: The fact that $A$ has rank 1 doesn't mean, that each column are the same.

Comment: @user153012 First, this is an example, so it is irrelevant if the general matrix has this property or not.... . And second, if a matrix has rank $1$ you can prove that any two rows are proportional... And the same about the columns... So it actually means that the columns are proportional (not equal).... But as I said, this is irrelevant.

Comment: Given $\text{rank}(A)=1$, how can $a_1=\cdots=a_n=0$ be a case? How do you get $a_{1,n}=1$ in that case?

Comment: @SamuelLijin What is the rank of the matrix below? What are the eigenvalues? $$A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1  \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \end{bmatrix}  \\$$

Comment: @SamuelLijin And there are many other nilpotent matrices of rank one.... That is just one such example, you don't get $a_{1,n}=1$ in all examples.

Answer (score 1):

We note that generally we have that:

$$\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{M})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i},$$

Where $\lambda_{i}$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $\mathbf{M}$ (a proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546155/proof-that-the-trace-of-a-matrix-is-the-sum-of-its-eigenvalues)). Therefore in your case we have:

$$\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}$$

Where $\lambda_{i}$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$. This is the case because the sum of eigenvalues of $\mathbf{B}$ must be $0$ as $\operatorname{Tr}(\mathbf{B})=0$ as we are told.

Comment: Yes, but sadly these are just the sum of the eigenvalues, but we don't know anything about what are the eigenvalues.