# How to obtain the sum of squared eigenvalues without finding the eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to obtain sum of square of eigenvalues without finding eigenvalues of a matrix?

Answer (score 10):

The eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$. The sum of the eigenvalues of any matrix (with algebraic multiplicity) is the trace. So the sum of the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$ (with algebraic multiplicity) is the trace of $A^2$.

Comment: Thanks. But why are the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$?

Comment: @Elessarr If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with eigenvector $x$ then $A^2x=A(Ax)=A(\lambda x)=\lambda Ax=\lambda^2 x$. Ensuring the multiplicities agree is a somewhat more difficult problem.

Answer (score 2):

Trace of a Matrix is the sum of its Eigenvalues

[Proof that the Trace of a Matrix is the sum of its Eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546155/proof-that-the-trace-of-a-matrix-is-the-sum-of-its-eigenvalues)

Comment: Your answer, combining with Ian's answer gives a more complete response.

Answer (score 0):

For any $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|^2 = \min_{\det(S)\neq 0} \|S^{-1}AS\|_F$$
$\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$.