# How to show that $\sum_{k=1}^n |a_{kk}| \le \sum_{k=1}^n |\lambda_k|$ for hermitian matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I see that this is not true in general.

[Is it true that $\sum_{k=1}^n |a_{kk}| \le \sum_{k=1}^n |\lambda_k|$ for any complex square matrix $A$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1463660/is-it-true-that-sum-k-1n-a-kk-le-sum-k-1n-lambda-k-for-any-com?noredirect=1#comment2980667_1463660)

But it is true in hermitian matrix. How to prove that this is true?

Comment: The [Schur-Horn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Horn_theorem) is related, but doesn't quite help us here.

Comment: This is a direct consequence of Thompson-Sing theorem (see thm 2.4 of [Chi-Kwong Li's notes](http://www.math.wm.edu/~ckli/ima/note-1.pdf)), but the theorem is perhaps an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is false for some complex matrices, eg. $\begin{pmatrix}5&-4\\6&-5\end{pmatrix}$; yet, it is true for any normal matrix.

Proof. Let $A=[a_{i,j}]$ be a normal matrix and $spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)_i$. There is $U$ (unitary) s.t. $A=Udiag((\lambda_i)_i)U^*$. Then, for every $i$, $a_{i,i}=\sum_{j} \lambda_j u_{i,j}\overline{u_{i,j}}$. Thus $\sum_i |a_{i,i}|\leq \sum_j|\lambda_j|\sum_i |u_{i,j}|^2=\sum_j|\lambda_j|$.

We can do better (cf. user1551 post). For any matrix $A$, $\sum_i |a_{i,i}|\leq \sum_i s_i$ where the $(s_i)_i$ are the singular values of $A$.

Proof. There are unitary $U,V$ s.t. $A=Udiag((s_i)_i)V$; let $a_{j,j}=r_jexp(i\theta_j)$ and $D=diag(exp(-i\theta_j)_j)$. One has $DA=DUdiag(s_i)V$ or $A'=Wdiag(s_i)V$ where the elements of the diagonal of $A'$ are the $|a_{i,i}|$ and $W$ is unitary. Thus $|a_{i,i}|=\sum_j w_{i,j}s_jv_{j,i}$ and $\sum_i|a_{i,i}|=\sum_js_j\sum_iw_{i,j}v_{j,i}\leq \sum_js_j$ by Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: Nice and simple! +1. And I like that you tried to prove things in weaker settings.

Comment: @ user1551 , thanks; in fact I did not know thm 2.4 given by Chi-Kwon-Li  :)