# How is the trace of a linear transformation related to the characteristic equation of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, trace

I've been staring at this problem for a while now, and I just can't seem to figure it out. Any help is appreciated. I feel like I am overlooking something simple.

Let the characteristic equation of a linear transformation $T$ be $t^4 + 3t^2 + 5$. What is the trace of $T$?

Comment: This may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546155/proof-that-the-trace-of-a-matrix-is-the-sum-of-its-eigenvalues

Comment: The trace is the negative of the $t^{n-1}$ coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

The trace is the sum of characteristic roots, so if the characteristic polynomial $p(t)$ has leading term $t^n$, then the term of degree $n-1$ will have coefficient $-a$ where $a$ is the trace.

$$ p(t) = \prod_{i=1}^n (t-\lambda_i) = t^n - (\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i) t^{n-1} +\ldots $$

where the product and sum are both indexed by counting characteristic roots according to multiplicity.

Comment: Oh that makes so much more sense! So in this case, the n-1 term is 0t^3 so the trace would be 0.

Comment: Yes, that is the case here.