# For each $v\in V$, $\exists n\in\Bbb{N}$, such that $T^nv=v$.

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $F$ be a field and $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $F$. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear transformation such that for every $v\in V$ there exists $n\in\Bbb{N}$ with $T^nv=v$.

1. Show that it $F=\Bbb{C}$, then $T$ is diagonalizable.
2. Show that if $\mathrm{char}(F)>0$, then there exists a non diagonalizable $T$ satisfying the above hypothesis.

Let $\{\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_k\}$ be a basis for $V$ over $F$. Let $n_i\in \Bbb{N}$ be an integer such that $T^{n_i}\alpha_i=\alpha_i$. Let $N=\max\{n_i:1\le i\le k\}$. Then $T^Nv=v$ for all $v\in V$. I could do this much. What next?

Comment: Proofs that it is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ were done today [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2766934/simple-proof-that-if-an-i-then-mathrmtra-1-overline-mathrmtra), probably there are previous questions as well. For the example in positive characteristic take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ in characteristic $p$. Then $A(v_1,v_2)^T=(v_1+v_2,v_2)^T=r(v_1,v_2)^T$ only when $r=1$ and $v_2=0$. So, no basis of eigenvectors. And $A^p(v_1,v_2)^T=(v_1+pv_2,v_2)^T=(v_1,v_2)^T$.

Comment: Shouldn't you take the lcm instead of max?