# Accelerated Randomized Coordinate Descent

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

This paper is by a famous professor. It has several hundreds of citations. There must be someone who understands this paper. If someone out there is experienced in optimization, please have a look at this.

In *Coordinate Descent Algorithms*

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10107-015-0892-3

by Stephen J. Wright an assumption (page 14) is given by:

**Assumption 1** *The function $f$ in $\text{ min } f(x) $ is convex and uniformly Lipschitz continuously
differentiable, and attains its minimum value $f^{*}$ on a set $S$. There is a finite $R_{0}$ such
that the level set for f defined by $x_0$ is bounded, that is,
$$
\max _{x^{*} \in \mathcal{S}} \max _{x}\left\{\left\|x-x^{*}\right\|: f(x) \leq f\left(x^{0}\right)\right\} \leq R_{0}
$$*

Then in the part dealing with **accelerated randomized coordinate descent** (page 19) it is stated:

**Theorem 2:** *Suppose that Assumption 1 holds, and define
$$
S_{0}:=\sup _{x^{*} \in \mathcal{S}} L_{\max }\left\|x^{0}-x^{*}\right\|^{2}+\left(f\left(x^{0}\right)-f^{*}\right) / n^{2}
$$
Then for all $k\ge0$ we have

\begin{aligned} E&(f(x^k)) - f^* \nonumber \\&\le S_0 \frac{\sigma }{L_\mathrm{max}} \left[ \left( 1+ \frac{\sqrt{\sigma /L_\mathrm{max}}}{2n} \right) ^{k+1} - \left( 1- \frac{\sqrt{\sigma /L_\mathrm{max}}}{2n} \right) ^{k+1} \right] ^{-2} \\
&\le S_0 \left( \frac{n}{k+1} \right) ^2. 
\end{aligned}

where $\sigma$ is the modulus of strong convexity and $L_{\text{max}}$ is the coordinate Lipschitz constant.

**Then he concludes the following:** *The term
$$
\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{\sigma / L_{\max }}}{2 n}\right)^{k+1}
$$
eventually dominates the second term
$$
\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{\sigma / L_{\max }}}{2 n}\right)^{k+1}
$$
so that the linear convergence rate suggested by this expression is significantly faster than the corresponding rate
$$
            E\left[f\left(x^{k}\right)\right]-f^{*} \leq\left(1-\frac{\sigma}{n L_{\max }}\right)^{k}\left(f\left(x^{0}\right)-f^{*}\right) \quad \forall k \geq 1
$$
for Algorithm 3* (which is the randomized coordinate descent without acceleration).

**Finally my problem:** I just cant follow his logic and cant see why this expression is significantly faster than the other one.

I am very thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

To see why the convergence rate is faster, you can compare two quantities: $1-\frac{\sigma}{n L_{\max}}$ and $\Bigl[ \bigl(1+\frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{2n}\bigr)^{k+1} - \bigl(1-\frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{2n}\bigr)^{k+1}\Bigr]^{-2}$. When $k$ becomes larger, the later one can be represented as

$$ \frac{1}{\biggl( \bigl(1+\frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{2n}\bigr)^{k+1} - \bigl(1-\frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{2n}\bigr)^{k+1} \biggr)^2} \approx \frac{1}{\biggl( \bigl(1+\frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{2n}\bigr)^{k+1} \biggr)^2} = \Biggl( \frac{1}{\bigl(1+\frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{2n}\bigr)^2} \Biggr)^{k+1}. $$

Now using first-order Taylor expansion we have $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} \approx 1-2x$. Thus the rate can be further approximated by

$$ \frac{1}{\bigl(1+\frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{2n}\bigr)^2} \approx 1 - \frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{n} < 1 - \frac{\sigma/L_{max}}{n}. $$

The improvement by a factor of $\sqrt{L_{\max}/\sigma}$ in the number of iterations can be seen by the following formula:

$$ (1-\rho)^k < \epsilon \Rightarrow k > \frac{\log (1/\epsilon)}{\log(1/(1-\rho))} \approx \frac{1}{\rho} \log (1/\epsilon) , $$

where you substitute $\rho = \frac{\sigma/L_{max}}{n}$ and $\rho = \frac{\sqrt{\sigma/L_{\max}}}{n}$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have no idea how much time I spend to figure this out but still did not make any progress...

This leads me to my next question: How am I supposed to be aware of all these thoughts that are not stated in the paper? Do you have any recommendation regarding another paper or book that helps to understand the paper of Wright?  Or did you maybe write down your thoughts about this paper back then? Many thanks again!

Comment: It's mostly about how are you familiar with the topic. I'd say you keep reading papers like this and get yourself familiar with these things by deriving from scratch. I don't think there is particular book or paper talking about such things

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately this is the first research paper I have to read and present in class. So you can imagine how obscure some statements appear to me...