# Proof that the Trace of a Matrix is the sum of its Eigenvalues for non diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[Proof that the Trace of a Matrix is the sum of its Eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546155/proof-that-the-trace-of-a-matrix-is-the-sum-of-its-eigenvalues)
How does the proof given by Prof.Ted Shriffin for the above question work when the matrix is non diagonalizable? 
In the video which has the same proof https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OLl_reBXY-g&list=PLlXfTHzgMRUIqYrutsFXCOmiqKUgOgGJ5&index=20 Prof.Pavel says that we have to deal the proof in a more subtle way when the matrix is non diagonalizable.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this proof for a defective matrix. Is there a specific aspect you are concerned about?

Comment: Why do you think the proof by Ted *Shifrin* assumes that the matrix is not defective? It seems to me that it works as written for all matrices (with the helpful explanation in the comment by MEB).