# Can we say that $\text {tr}\ (A) = 0\ $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix with $A^3 + A = 0.$ Can we say that $\text {tr}\ (A) = 0\ $?

I think it's true but can't prove it. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it's true. Sum of the roots of the characteristic equation is the trace of the matrix

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546155/proof-that-the-trace-of-a-matrix-is-the-sum-of-its-eigenvalues

Comment: @user60016 consider the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $x^3+x$.
Then the real Jordan form of $A$ can have, consequently, two kinds of blocks:

- 0 blocks of dimension 1
- 2-dimensional blocks associated to rotations of  $\pi/2$

In both cases the trace is equal to 0.

Recalling that the trace of $A$ is invariant for conjugation you have done.

Observe that this is not true over the complex numbers: $A=i I$ satisfies $A^3+A=0$ but $trA \neq 0$.

Comment: It is possible to find an analogue of classical complex Jordan form over reals, allowing as diagonal blocks some rotations 2 -dimensional blocks associated to the complex eighenvalues.

Comment: It is described, for example, here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form in the section about real matrices.

Comment: How can $2$-dimensional blocks associated to rotations of $\frac {\pi} {2}$ be a Jordan block? All such blocks are of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.$ This is not looking like a Jordan block as the Jordan blocks are upper triangular matrices with super-diagonal entries all equal to $1.$

Comment: The matrix of rotation through an angle $\frac {\pi} {2}$ is clearly not upper triangular.

Comment: I think the Jordan canonical form of a matrix can only make sense if all it's eigenvalues are lying inside the ground field from which the entries of the matrix are taken.

Comment: Please, read the Wikipedia article: it is well explained.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted your answer after reading this article in wikipedia from the link provided by you in one of your comments above.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to approach the proof is to use the minimal polynomial of $A$. If $K$ is the minimal polynomial of $A$, then any other polynomial $Q$ with $Q(A)=0$ is a multiple of $K$. Hence, the eigenvalues of $A$ are either $0$, $i$ or $-i$. Moreover, as $A$ is a real matrix, the sum of its eigenvalues must be a real number. In order to clarify this, consider a characteristic equation as below:

$$ a_1 x^n+a_2x^{n-1}+ ...+a_{n+1}=0$$
Then, the sum of the eigenvalues is $\frac{-a_2}{a_1}$.

To conclude the given fact, it's enough to observe that the only real number made by adding $0,-i,i$ together is $0$. So, we are done since $tr(A)$ is the sum of its eigenvalues.

PS: the link below may be useful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_(linear_algebra)

Comment: Trace of a matrix is sum of its eigenvalues not sum of its distinct eigenvalues. So considering $T(A^3)=a_1^3+a_2^3$, is not right, I think.

Answer (score -2):

the trace of the matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues, Here  $i,-i,0$ are  the eigenvalues of the given equation $A^3+A=0$ and the sum of its eigenvalues is zero,
So the trace of the matrix is $0$.

A matrix with real entries often has non-real eigenvalues.

Comment: we take only real entries...

Comment: @JCAA thank you for correcting , now I edited my answer

Comment: You should mention it clearly as to why $i$ and $-i$ are appearing as eigenvalues of $A$ over $\Bbb C$ with same multiplicities. Your argument is not yet complete and precise in my view @Venkat. You should argue as "Either $A = 0$ or $i$ and $-i$ should appear as roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ with same multiplicities (this time with proper justification) for otherwise the characteristic polynomial of $A$ will not lie in $\Bbb R[X].$"