# Prove that trace equals sum of eigenvalues using spectral decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

$\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left<#1\right|}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\left<#1 | #2\right>}
\newcommand{\tr}[1]{\text{tr}\left(#1\right)}
$There are [other ways](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546155/proof-that-the-trace-of-a-matrix-is-the-sum-of-its-eigenvalues) of doing this, but out of curiosity I'm trying to use the spectral decomposition theorem to prove the statement in the title.

Due to the spectral decomposition theorem, a normal matrix $N$ can be written as:
$$
N = \sum_j \nu_j \ket{w_j}\bra{w_j}
$$
where $\nu_j$s are the eigenvalues and $\ket{w_j}$s are their associated eigenvectors.

This can be used to prove that the trace of $N$ equals the sum of its eigenvalues:
$$
\tr{N} =
\sum_i \bra{i} N \ket{i} =
\sum_i \bra{i} \left( \sum_j \nu_j \ket{w_j}\bra{w_j} \right) \ket{i} =
\sum_j \nu_j \sum_i \braket{i}{w_j} \braket{w_j}{i} =
\sum_j \nu_j \braket{w_j}{w_j} =
\sum_j \nu_j \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

We also know that any linear operator $A$ can be written as:

$$
A = B + iC \tag{2}\label{2}
$$

where $B$ and $C$ are Hermitian matrices. Hermiticity implies normality, so the spectral decomposition and \eqref{1} can be used on them to write:

$$
\tr{A} = \tr{B + iC} = \tr{B} + i\tr{C} = \sum_k \beta_k + i \sum_l \gamma_l \tag{3}\label{3}
$$

where $\beta_k$ and $\gamma_l$ are the eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$ respectively. This is quite promising but we still need to prove that

$$
\sum_k \beta_k + i \sum_l \gamma_l = \sum_m \alpha_m \tag{4}\label{4}
$$

where $\alpha_m$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd try one of those "other ways" myself.

Comment: You can use the fact that the trace is cyclic and therefore invariant under basis change. So you might as well start with $N$ being diagonal.

Comment: Your equation on the eigenvalues does not generally hold. We can guarantee that $A$ can be decomposed into $A = B + iC$ with this relationship between the eigenvalues whenever $A$ is normal, but not in the general case.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Eq. (3) holds in general, right? If it does, then eq. (4) has to hold too because $\sum_k \beta_k + i \sum_l \gamma_l = \text{tr} \left( A \right) = \sum_m \alpha_m$ Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @AttilaKun Sorry, I had read that incorrectly: I thought you meant $\alpha_k = \beta_k + i \gamma_k$

Comment: @BenGrossmann No worries, I agree that wouldn't hold.

Answer (score 0):

For $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, its characteristic polynomial can be writen as
$$|\lambda I-A|=
\begin{vmatrix}
\lambda-x_{11} & x_{12} & \cdots & x_{1n}\\
x_{21} & \lambda-x_{22} & \cdots & x_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots &        &\vdots\\
x_{n1} & x_{n2} & \cdots & \lambda-x_{nn}\\
\end{vmatrix}=(\lambda-\lambda_1)(\lambda-\lambda_2)\cdots(\lambda-\lambda_l)
$$

compare the coefficient of $\lambda^{n-1}$.

Comment: This does not answer the question being asked