# Matrices that have same complex eigenvalues with the same algebraic multiplicities have same trace?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

> **Question**: Matrices that have same complex eigenvalues with the same algebraic multiplicities have same trace?

I was unable to find counter example

(For simplicity, I was searching for two $2×2$ matrices with real entries that same complex eigenvalues with same algebraic multiplicities but having different trace. So I have considered

$A=\begin{bmatrix}-2&-1\\5&2\end{bmatrix}$ clearly $A$ has complex eigenvalues $i, -i$ & both have algebraic multiplicity $1$. But I was **unable** to find matrix $B$ that have same eigenvalues with same algebraic multiplicities but having different trace )

Is the above statement is true?

Please help.

Comment: Trace is the sum of the eigen values, so  there is no such example.

Comment: Does it work even if the matrix is not diagonalisable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, the trace of a matrix is equal to th3 sum of its eigenvalues (algebraic multiplicities included).

[Proof that the trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546155/proof-that-the-trace-of-a-matrix-is-the-sum-of-its-eigenvalues)