# $\log(\det A) = tr(\log(A))$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

I want to know that if the equation in the title  always holds?   I have generated a random Hermitian matrix $A$, and then compute $\log(\det A)$ and $ tr(\log(A))$ in matlab, it is not equal. So I'm really puzzled.

Can you give me the proof of this equation if it is true.
Thanks in advance

I just show an example:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}30.9186 + 0.0000i & -0.5120 - 0.0197i
 \\-0.5120 + 0.0197i & 10.3822 + 0.0000i
 \end{bmatrix}$$

$K>> log2(det(A))$

$ans =   8.3253 + 0.0000i$

$K>> trace(log2(A))$

$ans =8.3264 + 0.0000i$

what's wrong about it?

it is essentially different from these problem such as

[How to prove $\det(e^A) = e^{\operatorname{tr}(A)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322640/how-to-prove-detea-e-operatornametra)

because I think this equation is totally wrong, so I don't know why it can be proved.

Comment: Do you know a formula for the determinant or trace, maybe in terms of eigenvalues?

Comment: yes, but I don't know how to proof this equation

Comment: First you have to ensure that the expression $\log(A)$ makes sense (this is not the case for all hermitian matrices).

Comment: Continuing the @Alpha001 comment: To answer this, you need a definition of $\log(A)$.  So begin there.

Comment: I just add an example, do you know what's wrong with it

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP does not read answers and comments.

Comment: @user91684 OP has read and even answered to comments, and even if OP wouldn't read comments, that still wouldn't make the question off-topic, so your comment doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is hermitian $>0$, then your formula is valid is we choose the principal logarithm  $(\log(re^{i\theta})=\log(r)+i\theta$ where $\theta\in (-\pi,\pi)$).

If $A$ is invertible hermitian, your formula is -in general- not valid; example

$A=-I_2$. The required equality is (*) $\log(1)=2\log(-1)$.

If we choose the following $\log$: $\log(re^{i\theta})=\log(r)+i\theta$ where $\theta\in (-\pi+1/10,\pi+1/10)$, then $\log(1)=0,\log(-1)=i\pi$ and (*) is not satisfied.

EDIT. About your edit, you are not serious.

If $spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)$, then $spectrum(e^A)=(e^{\lambda_i})$.  Therefore, $\det(e^A)=\Pi_i e^{\lambda_i}$ and $e^{tr(A)}=e^{\Sigma_i \lambda_i}$. I hope that you are convinced...